# Add additional columns to binding source when binding to EF table via sql override

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, entity-framework

Hi I have a BindingSource that is getting bound as

```
sql = "select a.*, b.col3 from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.col2 = b.col1";
context.Table1.SqlQuery(sql).ToList();
BindingSource1.DataSource = context.Table1.Local.ToBindingList();
```

However when I access the BindingSource1 it has only columns from table1. I wonder if there is an easy way to add the col3 from table2 so I wouldn't really need to rewrite a lot of logic on that form. I tried to get away with linq to ef but I'm not getting the same result set as I was getting using sql override (real life query is much complicated) and would like not to introduce query override each time I need to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know how your BindingSource1 is used I can only comment on the EF part. The reason you only see parts from Table1 is because you select from that table with: `context.Table1.SqlQuery()`. This will just try and match your query with the class Table1 and col3 is not part of it.

If the real life query is complex it might be better create a database view and hook that up to EF and select from that instead. Or you could do a non-entity select and map it to a class: `context.Database.SqlQuery<Class>(sql)`

Comment: If Table1 has children ICollection<Table3> how would I populate that in my new class?

Comment: I'm not sure that would work in this case, or atleast not automatically that I know of. This is one of the things that the EF mapping gives you and it can be really powerful, but do you need anything from Table3 in this binding? If you do then one thing you could do instead of what I stated above is to do a mapping for Table2 to Table1 just as you have for Table3 and just get col3 from the Table2 object. If you are doing this then I would suggest that you use the Include methods that EF have for querying so you don't get a lot of calls to the database.

Comment: How would I bind a column into BindingSource that is bound to Table1 to get the data from Table2 or how would I get that data into a gridview? That binding source is actually binding the gridview and I need to bring some data back from child table. This is a winforms app and using edmx EF. I haven't worked with edmx for past 5 years (if I was using EF after 2013 it was code-first) and never with winforms, so really sorry if question is basic.

Comment: That is a good question, but if you are not doing it for Table3 then I don't see the need for this approach at all. Create a new class that contains properties for all the columns you want in the grid view and select into that like I showed above (the syntax might not be 100% since I can't test it atm). Otherwise I think I might be missing what you are after sadly. Do you want to do anything else with the data other than to show it in the grid view?